# Как в языке С провести все вычисления в отдельной функции?

Tags: c, функции

У меня есть программа которая конвентирует ед. измерения, мне нужно всю вычислительную часть убрать в функцию, а в программе только вызывать эту функцию, или как-то так. Если можно изложить алгоритм выполнения такого задания, буду благодарен.

Сама программа:

```
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "locale.h" 

int main () 
{ 
 float a;
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
 printf ("Программа для конвертации см в м,км\n");  
  do{
  printf("Введите количество сантиметров:\n"); 
  scanf ("%f",&a);
 }while (a<= 0 && (printf("Ошибка, a<0\n")) );
 printf ("Метров=%.2f\n",a/100); 
 printf ("Километров=%.2f\n",a/100000);  

 return 0; 
}
```

блок-схема как должно в итоге работать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Абсолютно непонятно с чем именно у вас проблема.

Comment: Положите все в функцию и вызывайте ее в main, что ж тут сложного

Comment: Все очень просто, я не умею этого делать, если можно статью об этом или еще какой-либо материал?

Comment: [Тут вроде доступно написано](http://cppstudio.com/post/396/) - эт C++ и [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/6471/) - C

Comment: [Гриффисты - Изучаем программирование на C](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19710905/) или [Гукин - C для чайников](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2354016/).

Comment: Спасибо за ресурсы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем функцию *func1* и копипастим в неё участки исходного кода, отвечающие за вычисления:

```
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "locale.h" 

void func1(void) {
 float a;
  do{
  printf("Введите количество сантиметров:\n"); 
  scanf ("%f",&a);
 }while (a<= 0 && (printf("Ошибка, a<0\n")) );
 printf ("Метров=%.2f\n",a/100); 
 printf ("Километров=%.2f\n",a/100000);  
}


int main () 
{ 
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
 printf ("Программа для конвертации см в м,км\n");  
 func1();
 return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант с передачей переменной в функцию:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "locale.h"

void func1(float a){

printf("Метров=%.2f\n", a/100);
printf("Километров=%.2f\n", a/100000);}

int main (){

float a = 1;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

printf ("Программа для конвертации см в м,км\n");
while(a > 0){
    printf("Введите количество сантиметров или 0 для завершения программы:\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    if(a != 0) func1(a);}

return 0;}
```